# Refresh twitter bootstrap form wizards after submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to refresh a form wizard after submit to avoid page reload. I'm using the plugin twitter bootstrap form wizard http://vinceg.github.io/twitter-bootstrap-wizard/ 
So far I've tried with form.reset(); and $("#wizard").load(location.href + " #wizard");

Both methods don't seem to work, in the first case the form is cleared but doesn't take me to the first step of the form, in the second case it takes me to the first step but the wizard is not loaded and show me the submit button even if i'm still on step one. I haven't post the code because iq uite long as i'm using jquery validator as well, but I can post it if required.

This is the javascript code

```
 var handleFormWizard = function () {

            var form = $('#newUserForm');
            var error = $('.alert-danger', form);
            var success = $('.alert-success', form);
            var warning = $('.alert-warning', form);

            // Validate username field to avoid spaces between words
            $.validator.methods.whitespace_username = function( value, element ) {
              return this.optional( element ) || /^\S*$/i.test( value );
            };

            // Validate username field to make sure is only numbers and letters
            $.validator.methods.username = function( value, element ) {
              return this.optional( element ) || /^[A-Za-z0-9_]+$/i.test( value );
            };

            // Validate password Minimum eight characters, at least one uppercase letter, one lowercase letter, one number and one special character
            $.validator.methods.password = function( value, element ) {
              return this.optional( element ) || /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*?&]{8,}$/i.test( value );
            };

            form.validate({
                doNotHideMessage: true, //this option enables to show the error/success messages on tab switch.
                errorElement: 'span', //default input error message container
                errorClass: 'help-block help-block-error', // default input error message class
                focusInvalid: false, // do not focus the last invalid input

                rules: {

                    userFirstname: { required: true },
                    userLastname: { required: true },
                    userEmail: { 

                        required: true,
                        email: true,
                        remote: {

                              type: "post",
                              data: {
                                ajax_action: 'checkEmail',
                                userEmail: function() {
                                    return $( "#userEmail" ).val();
                                }

                              } 
                        },

                        async: false
                    },

                    docTypology: {

                      required: {
                        depends: function () {
                            return $('#docNumber').val() != '';

                        }
                      }

                    },

                    docNumber: {

                      required: {
                        depends: function () {
                            return $('#docTypology').val() == "1" || $('#docTypology').val() == "2";

                        }
                      }

                    },

                    userUsername: { 

                        required: true,
                        whitespace_username: true,
                        username: true,
                        remote: {

                              type: "post",
                              data: {
                                ajax_action: 'checkUsername',
                                userUsername: function() {
                                    return $( "#userUsername" ).val();
                                }

                              } 
                        },

                        async: false
                    },

                    userPassword: {
                      required: true,
                      password: true

                    },
                    userWebsite: {
                        required: false,
                        url: true
                    },

                    "userGroup[]": {
                      required: true
                    }

                },

                // mostro messaggi di errore personalizzati
                messages: {

                    userFirstname: "Compila il campo nome condòmino!",
                    userLastname: "Compila il campo cognome condòmino!",

                    userEmail: {
                      required: "Compila il campo indirizzo email!",
                      remote: "Questo indirizzo email è già registrato, per favore scegline un altro!",
                      email: "L'indirizzo email non è in un formato valido"
                    },
                    docTypology:{
                        required: "Seleziona tipologia documento"
                    },
                    docNumber: {
                        required: "Inserisci il numero di documento",
                    },
                    userUsername: {
                      required: "Compila il campo nome utente!",
                      remote: "Questo nome utente è già registrato, per favore scegline un altro!",
                      whitespace_username: "Il campo nome utente non può contenere spazi vuoti!",
                      username: "Il campo nome utente può solo contenere lettere e numeri"

                    },
                    userPassword: {
                      required: "Compila il campo password condòmino!",
                      password: "Sicurezza password minimo 8 caratteri (maiuscole, minuscole, numeri, simboli)"
                    },
                    userWebsite: {
                        url: "Il campo sito internet non è nel formato corretto, per favore utilizza il formato http://www.nomesito.estensione"
                    },
                    "userGroup[]": "Il campo condominio del condòmino è richiesto!"

                },

                errorPlacement: function(error, element) { // render error placement for each input type
                    error.insertAfter(element); // for other inputs, just perform default behavior
                },

                invalidHandler: function(event, validator) { //display error alert on form submit   
                    success.hide();
                    error.show();
                    App.scrollTo(error, -200);
                },

                highlight: function(element) { // hightlight error inputs
                    $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error'); // set error class to the control group
                },

                unhighlight: function(element) { // revert the change done by hightlight
                    $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error'); // set error class to the control group

                },

                success: function(label) {
                    label.addClass('valid').closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success'); // set success class to the control group

                },

                submitHandler: function(form) {
                    // var user_username = $('#userUsername').val();
                    // localStorage.setItem('userUsername', user_username);

                    // Actions when form is submitted
                    var ajaxRequest = $.ajax({

                        type: form.method,
                        data: $(form).serialize(),
                        dataType: 'JSON',
                        async: 'true', 

                        beforeSend: function() {
                            // Show loader
                            $(".loader").show();
                        },

                        // Se tutto va a buon fine mostro un messaggio di successo utilizzando sweetalert
                        success: function(response, xhr) {

                            // Hide loader
                            $(".loader").hide();

                            if (response.error_code == '400' || response.error_code == '500' && response.error_status == null) {
                                // Add class alert danger to the message
                                $('.alert', $('.horizontal-form')).addClass('alert-danger').show();
                                // Show error message
                                $('#error_message').html(response.error_message);
                                // Remove default validation error message from template
                                $('#error_message').get(0).nextSibling.remove();
                                // reset form fields
                                form.reset();
                                // Scroll back to show error message
                                scrollTo(error, -200);

                            }

                            if (response.error_code == '200') {

                                // Add class alert danger to the message
                                $('.alert', $('.horizontal-form')).addClass('alert-success').show();
                                // Show error message
                                $('#error_message').html(response.error_message);
                                // Remove default validation error message from template
                                $('#error_message').get(0).nextSibling.remove();
                                // Remove class alert danger if was left by previous validation
                                $('.alert', $('.horizontal-form')).removeClass('alert-danger');
                                // Scroll back to show success message
                                scrollTo(success, -200);

                                // check if checkbox is thicked then execute xmlhttprequest
                                if($("#userLetter").prop('checked') == true){

                                    // Get username from the form field and create new variable
                                    var user_username = $('#userUsername').val();
                                    // Get password from the form field and create new variable
                                    var user_password = $('#userPassword').val();
                                    // Get lastname from the form field and create new variable
                                    var user_last_name = $('#userLastname').val();
                                     // Get lastname from the form field and create new variable
                                    var user_first_name = $('#userFirstname').val();
                                    // Create variable with params to pass XMLHttpRequest
                                    var params = 'user_username='+user_username+'&user_password='+user_password+'&user_first_name='+user_first_name+'&user_last_name='+user_last_name;

                                    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
                                    request.open('POST', '/km-users/printLetter', true);
                                    request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
                                    request.responseType = 'blob';

                                    request.onload = function() {

                                      // Only handle status code 200
                                      if(request.status === 200) {
                                        // Try to find out the filename from the content disposition `filename` value
                                        var disposition = request.getResponseHeader('content-disposition');
                                        var matches = /"([^"]*)"/.exec(disposition);
                                        var filename = (matches != null && matches[1] ? matches[1] : 'Lettera_cliente_'+ user_last_name +'_'+new Date().getTime()+'.pdf');

                                        // The actual download
                                        var blob = new Blob([request.response], { type: 'application/pdf' });
                                        var link = document.createElement('a');
                                        link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                                        link.download = filename;

                                        document.body.appendChild(link);

                                        link.click();

                                        document.body.removeChild(link);
                                      }

                                      // some error handling should be done here...
                                    };

                                    request.send(params);

                                }

                                // Reset also select2 filed after form
                                // $("#multiple").val("").trigger("change.select2");
                                // Reset form only after XMLHttpRequest otherwise it doesn't transmit form values

                                 form[0].reset();

                                 // $("#newuser_wizard").load(location.href + " #newuser_wizard");


                            }

                            if (response.error_code == '500' && response.error_status == 'warning') {

                                // Add class alert danger to the message
                                $('.alert', $('.horizontal-form')).addClass('alert-warning').show();
                                // Show error message
                                $('#error_message').html(response.error_message);
                                // Remove default validation error message from template
                                $('#error_message').get(0).nextSibling.remove();
                                // Remove class alert danger if was left by previous validation
                                $('.alert', $('.horizontal-form')).removeClass('alert-danger');
                                // reset form fields
                                form.reset();
                                // Scroll back to show success message
                                scrollTo(warning, -200);

                            }

                        },

                        error: function(jqXHR, exception) {

                            if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                                error_message = 'Siamo spiacenti non è stato possibile eseguire questa operazione, per favore contatta l\'amministratore di sistema.';
                            } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                                error_message = 'Siamo spiacenti non è stato possibile eseguire questa operazione, per favore contatta l\'amministratore di sistema.';
                            } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                                error_message = 'Siamo spiacenti non è stato possibile eseguire questa operazione, per favore contatta l\'amministratore di sistema.';
                            } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                                error_message = 'Siamo spiacenti non è stato possibile eseguire questa operazione, per favore contatta l\'amministratore di sistema.';
                            } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                                error_message = 'Siamo spiacenti non è stato possibile eseguire questa operazione, per favore contatta l\'amministratore di sistema.';
                            } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                                error_message = 'Siamo spiacenti non è stato possibile eseguire questa operazione, per favore contatta l\'amministratore di sistema.';
                            }

                            // Hide loader
                            $(".loader").hide();
                            // Add class alert danger to the message
                            $('.alert', $('.horizontal-form')).addClass('alert-danger').show();
                            // Show error message
                            $('#error_message').html(error_message);
                            // Remove default validation error message from template
                            $('#error_message').get(0).nextSibling.remove();
                            // Scroll back to show error message
                            scrollTo(error, -200);


                        }

                    });

                } 

            });


            var handleTitle = function(tab, navigation, index) {
                var total = navigation.find('li').length;
                var current = index + 1;
                // set wizard title
                $('.step-title', $('#newuser_wizard')).text('Step ' + (index + 1) + ' of ' + total);
                // set done steps
                jQuery('li', $('#newuser_wizard')).removeClass("done");
                var li_list = navigation.find('li');
                for (var i = 0; i < index; i++) {
                    jQuery(li_list[i]).addClass("done");
                }

                if (current == 1) {
                    $('#newuser_wizard').find('.button-previous').hide();
                    $('#newuser_wizard').find('.button-submit').hide();
                    $('#newuser_wizard').find('.button-next').show();
                } else {
                    $('#newuser_wizard').find('.button-previous').show();
                    $('#newuser_wizard').find('.button-next').show();
                    $('#newuser_wizard').find('.button-submit').hide();
                }

                if (current >= total) {
                    $('#newuser_wizard').find('.button-next').hide();
                    $('#newuser_wizard').find('.button-submit').show();

                }

                App.scrollTo($('.page-title'));
            }

            // default form wizard
            $('#newuser_wizard').bootstrapWizard({
                'nextSelector': '.button-next',
                'previousSelector': '.button-previous',

                onTabClick: function(tab, navigation, index, clickedIndex) {

                    success.hide();
                    error.hide();

                    if (form.valid() == false) {
                        return false;
                    }

                    handleTitle(tab, navigation, clickedIndex);
                },

                onNext: function(tab, navigation, index) {
                    success.hide();
                    error.hide();

                    if (form.valid() == false) {
                        return false;
                    }

                    handleTitle(tab, navigation, index);
                },

                onPrevious: function(tab, navigation, index) {
                    success.hide();
                    error.hide();

                    handleTitle(tab, navigation, index);
                },

                onTabShow: function(tab, navigation, index) {
                    var total = navigation.find('li').length;
                    var current = index + 1;
                    var $percent = (current / total) * 100;
                    $('#newuser_wizard').find('.progress-bar').css({
                        width: $percent + '%'
                    });
                }
            });

            $('#newuser_wizard').find('.button-previous').hide();

            $('#newuser_wizard .button-submit').click(function() {
                if (form.valid() == false) {
                    return false;
                }

            }).hide();

            // Remove error validation from typology field if is filled 
            $('#docTypology', form).change(function() {
                form.validate().element($(this));
            });
             // Remove error validation from multiple select field if is filled 
            $('#multiple', form).change(function () {
                form.validate().element($(this)); 
              });
    }
```

**UPDATE:**
I've moved the ajax call inside

```
$('#newuser_wizard .button-submit').click(function(e) {..}
```

and then when ajax success function is fired I've added the following:

```
// Reset also select2 filed after form
                                $("#multiple").val("").trigger("change.select2");
                                // Reset form only after XMLHttpRequest otherwise it doesn't transmit form values
                                $('#newUserForm').trigger("reset");
                                // Show first step of the wizard
                                $('#newuser_wizard a[href="#tab1"]').tab('show');
                                // Hide next button
                                $('#newuser_wizard').find('.button-previous').hide();
                                // Hide submit button
                                $('#newuser_wizard').find('.button-submit').hide();
                                // Show next button
                                $('#newuser_wizard').find('.button-next').show();
```

Now it seems to wor, it does reset the fomr and return to the first step of the wizard, the only problem is that if i try to submit the form for a second time and validator catch an error the the success message is still showing.

Comment: Show the error log and post the code which is causing the error.

Comment: Hi @MariosNikolaou i've added the javascript code

Comment: Show the error.

Comment: I don’t have any errors in the console.

Comment: Add input type="reset" in form

Comment: I would like to avoid to show reset button. Is there any way to reset the form automatically after submit and return to step one of form wizard?

Comment: Select input elements and set InnerHTML to empty.

Comment: Could you show to me how I can achieve this? Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this.Hope it helps.

```js
function init(){
   var el = document.getElementById("clr");
   el.addEventListener('click',clear);
 
 }
 
 function clear(){
   var elems = document.querySelectorAll("input");
  
   for(var i = 0;i < elems.length;i++){
     elems[i].value="";
   }
   
 }
 
 addEventListener('load',init)
```

```html
<form id="frm1">
 <input type="text" />
 <input type="email" />
 <input type="tel" />
</form>
<button id="clr">Clear</button>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your help, I've added it when ajax success is fired but doesn't work i'm afraid :(

Comment: Post the form code and how you fire ajax call with my code only, remove the rest of the code. Also, does it throw any errors on console?

Comment: Hi @MariosNikolaou I've added an update to my question